# how to kill a child thread if it is taking more than threshold time in linux

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

i am working one something where i need to kill a child thread if it is taking more than 10 mins to complete .

for example :

```
void *child_thread();
void parent_thread()
{
    pthread_t tid;
    pthread_create(&tid,NULL,child_thread,NULL);
    **pthread_join_on_wait(tid, NULL,10 mins);**
}
```

I couldn't able to find anything on Net something similar to join_on_wait or something like that .

Yes i could use , semaphore or conditions . But wanted to double check whether there is any generic way or not .

Comment: You shouldn't try to kill threads. Ever. That's bad approach. Find a stopping condition and let the thread self-stop.

Comment: if my child entered a loop ? then what would be the right thing to do

Comment: How about sleep for 10 minutes then kill the thread if it has not exited? That may not be what you are looking for but you have not described any constraints on the solution.

Comment: what if the child thread excited before 10 mins , parent will be idle for a while right . if the child didn't exit with in 10 mins , i am ready to kill it .

Comment: @manimuthuma Put a stop condition in that loop. For instance, at each step of the loop the thread should verify if it is still allowed to run.

Comment: @manimuthuma Just user a timer in the main thread. See for example [timer_create](http://linux.die.net/man/2/timer_create). The timer expiry will be signaled asynchronously.

Comment: Take a look at http://devel.ringlet.net/sysutils/timelimit/ You might be able to modify that for your purposes.

Comment: If you have a thread that's out of control, there is no safe way to terminate such a thread. So you will need to figure out another strategy.

Answer (score 0):

As already commented, you have to handle the timer in the parent thread. You can check periodically and do other work meanwhile.

It'd be nice of that thread to exit nicely, but this is not always possible. E.g., you're calling some untrusted 3rd party code. Web browsers do that all the time.

To terminate a thread from another one, you can send a signal to it. `pthread_kill` sends a signal to a specific thread.

You will need a signal handler that calls `pthread_exit` to kill that thread.

One thing to keep in mind is that any memory you allocated in that thread will not get released, and if you hold any locks, they'd stay as they were. Not a good thing.

I could tell you of a better approach, but it applies to c++, not to c.